# Symfony Doctrine query based on Many to Many related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a simple messaging system. Users are related to MessageThreads in ManyToMany relation. MessageThreads can either have many users (think of group chats or channels) or just two users (think of private messages).

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
   /**
     * HAS MANY: MessageThreads
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MessageThread", inversedBy="users", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="user_message_thread",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mthread_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $messageThreads;
...
}

class MessageThread
{
    /**
     * HAS MANY: Users
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="messageThreads", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $users;
...
}
```

Now considering that user has a method to open private chat with certain other user, I want to be able to identify if there already is a MessageThread between them (and them only), or should I create a new one

```
public function newPrivAction(Request $request, string $slug)
{
...
    // try locating a thread with ONLY current and $friend user
    if($thread = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MessageThread')->findOnePrivFor($this->getUser(), $friend)) {

        // ** dbg
        print "Old priv found #" . $thread->getId();
        die();
    }

    // or create a brand new thread
    else {

        $thread = new MessageThread();

        $thread
            ->addUser($this->getUser())
            ->addUser($friend)
        ;

        $em->persist($thread);
        $em->flush();

        // ** dbg
        print "New priv created #" . $thread->getId();
        die();
    }
...
}
```

My problem is I cannot truly figure out how to structure the `findOnePrivFor(...)` repository method. Ideally I would want a method that just finds a thread with ONLY THOSE users, but after few hours of googling I gave up on that. My second approach (or rather workaround) was to find users who belong to given thread and limit the users' count to 2. This one got me quite close - except the counting part which doesn't seem to work.

```
class MessageThreadRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findOnePrivFor(User $user1, User $user2)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('mt');
        $qb
            ->where(':user1 MEMBER OF mt.users')
            ->andWhere(':user2 MEMBER OF mt.users')
            //->andWhere('count(mt.users) = 2')                                 // ** fails
            //->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->count('mt.users'), 2))    // ** fails
            ->setMaxResults(1)

            ->setParameters([

                'user1' => $user1,
                'user2' => $user2
            ])
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Add a having clause to your query builder:

```php
$qb->join('mt.users', 'u')
   ->having('count(u.id) = 2'))
```